# Pivot table for non numerical data frame pandas

Tags: pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to create a chart from a large data set the structure is as below :
sample data frame :

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'climate':['hot','hot','hot','cold','cold'],0:['none','apple','apple','orange','grape'],1:['orange','none','grape','apple','banana'],2:['grape','kiwi','tomato','none','tomato']})
```

need to plot how many from each fruit exist in different climate ,I need two chart both hot and cold separately.

Pivot table and aggregation are not possible because no numerical values .
what method do you recommend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First do `melt` then `pd.crosstab`

```
s=df.melt('climate')
s=pd.crosstab(s.variable,s.value)
value     apple  banana  grape  kiwi  none  orange  tomato
variable                                                  
0             2       0      1     0     1       1       0
1             1       1      1     0     1       1       0
2             0       0      1     1     1       0       2
```

Comment: just another play on ur answer; dont think it is necessary to write another answer for it - ```df.melt('climate').groupby('climate').value.value_counts()```

Comment: @sammywemmy nice way ~

Comment: @sammywemmy@YOBEN_S Thank you.

Comment: @SA_H if this is what you need , would you like accept it ?

Comment: @YOBEN_S your method works better when dataset is list of objects.